# rsync command doesn't work when run as a systemd service

Tags: systemd, rsync, brace-expansion, systemd-timer

**summary:**

I am trying to set up a systemd timer to regularly backup a directory using the `rsync` command. I made an `rsync` command that works when run manually in a terminal, but it doesn't work correctly when run as a systemd timer.

**detailed explanation:**

As a simple example, I have following directory tree in `/home/trevor/test_dir/`:

```
dir_a/
   file_a.png
dir_b/
   file_b.png
dir_c/
   file_c.png
```

I want to use `rsync` to copy this directory to my SSD for backup (mounted at `/my_ssd/`). But I want to exclude the directories `dir_a` and `dir_b`. So I run the command

```sh
rsync -a --exclude={/dir_a,/dir_b} /home/trevor/test_dir/ /my_ssd/test_dir/
```

This command works when I run it from a terminal: it excludes the directories `dir_a` and `dir_b`, but keeps `dir_c`.

Next, I try to make a systemd service and timer to run that command routinely (note that I determined the following steps mostly from the [systemd/Timers page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers) on the Arch Linux Wiki). I make the following service file

`/etc/systemd/system/backup_test.service`:

```sh
[Unit]
Description=systemd backup test

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=rsync -a --exclude={/dir_a,/dir_b} /home/trevor/test_dir/ /my_ssd/test_dir/
```

and the following timer file which will run the command every 30 seconds (for example)

`/etc/systemd/system/backup_test.timer`:

```sh
[Unit]
Description=systemd backup test timer

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:*:0/30
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

I start the timer using `systemctl start backup_test.timer`. The timer does run every 30 seconds, but the "exclude" part seems to be ignored, and the entire directory is copied.

**debugging attempts:**

I tried the `rsync` command with multiple `--exclude` options instead of the brace expansion, in other words I used `--exclude=/dir_a --exclude=/dir_b` instead of `--exclude={/dir_a,/dir_b}`. This actually made the command work. So I think the problem is that the brace expansion is not being done properly.

Next, I tried to test a simpler command with brace expansion, to see if the brace expansion itself was the problem. So I replaced the `rsync` command in the systemd service with `touch /home/trevor/test{1,2}.txt`. This command created a file literally named `/home/trevor/test{1,2}.txt`. So I'm pretty sure the problem is that the brace expansion is not handled correctly by the systemd service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I figured this out on my own by reading the manual for systemd services (`man systemd.service`). The `ExecStart=` option doesn't directly support shell command lines, which I think is why the brace expansion was not being performed as intended. I got everything to work by passing my `rsync` command to `sh -c` in the `ExecStart=` line:

```sh
ExecStart=sh -c 'rsync -a --exclude={/dir_a,/dir_b} /home/trevor/test_dir/ /my_ssd/test_dir/'
```

**reference:**

```
$ man systemd.service
...
       Note that shell command lines are not directly supported. If shell
       command lines are to be used, they need to be passed explicitly to a
       shell implementation of some kind. Example:

           ExecStart=sh -c 'dmesg | tac'
...
```

Comment: Another alternative is to just expand the list of excluded directories yourself: `--exclude=/dir_a --exclude=/dir_b`. You can also use a file with an exclude list for rsync, which should also work.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the file option. Just to make note, that is the `--exclude-from=FILE` option.